# Is it possible to get a version number from the XAP file

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible for the silverlight client to get any of the assembly version information from the xap file it's downloaded.

Essentially, I need a way for the client to confirm that's in fact running the latest bits, if there's a better way I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to check while the application is running you could bring in System.Reflection and do something like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
if (assembly.FullName != null)
{
    string versionPart = assembly.FullName.Split(',')[1];
    string version = versionPart.Split('=')[1];

    // check version against something
}
```

Comment: I wonder why FullName is Ok, but GetName() is a security exception.

Comment: I am not really sure why, but MSDN says not to use GetName() in Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w2wdeze(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For client its ok by this following code

```
    public static string getAsmVersionInfo()
    {
        return "v " + ParseVersionNumber(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).ToString();
    }

    public static Version ParseVersionNumber(Assembly assembly)
    {
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName);
        return assemblyName.Version;
    }
```

But how can we learn that from Web side ? I would like to show as index.aspx's Title . There is a xap in ClientBin/ directory. We need to reach dll inside of it  on server side.

For this another solution available changing aspx page's Title from client side http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainala/archive/2008/11/23/changing-html-page-title-from-silverlight.aspx