# How can I find out the version number of Silverlight XAP from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, versioning

I have an ASP.NET application that includes a number of plugins written in Silverlight. How can I find out the .NET assembly versions of the Silverlight applications from within the web application ([not the Silverlight plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806777/is-it-possible-to-get-a-version-number-from-the-xap-file)), so that I can list the installed plugins in, for example, a Help | About box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A XAP file is a ZIP-formatted file.  You can open it with Winzip, extract the assemblies, and look at their version numbers.  This should all be possible using .NET zip library and Reflection within ASP.NET.

Comment: Sounds like a straightforward solution to me; thanks for the suggestion.